# _ready(): Node not found: "Pivot/Camera" + player falls through the floor

Tags: godot, collider, gdscript, godot-4

I'm relatively new to Godot 4.0.3. I have two problems which seem to depend on each other so I put both of them into one single question.

I know, these issues have been reported multiple times on other forums, but none of their solutions worked for me and when I try to fix one of them the other one occurs again or gives errors.

**My first problem (`_ready(): Node not found: "Pivot/Camera"`):**

my full script:

```
extends CharacterBody3D

@onready var camera = $Pivot/Camera

var gravity = -30
var max_speed = 8
var mouse_sensitivity = 0.002  # radians/pixel

#var velocity = Vector3()

func get_input():
    var input_dir = Vector3()
    # desired move in camera direction
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_up"):
        input_dir += -global_transform.basis.z
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_down"):
        input_dir += global_transform.basis.z
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        input_dir += -global_transform.basis.x
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        input_dir += global_transform.basis.x
    input_dir = input_dir.normalized()
    return input_dir

func _unhandled_input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion and Input.get_mouse_mode() == Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED:
        rotate_y(-event.relative.x * mouse_sensitivity)
        $Pivot.rotate_x(-event.relative.y * mouse_sensitivity)
        $Pivot.rotation.x = clamp($Pivot.rotation.x, -1.2, 1.2)

func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity.y += gravity * delta
    var desired_velocity = get_input() * max_speed

    velocity.x = desired_velocity.x
    velocity.z = desired_velocity.z
    move_and_slide()
```

Error:

```
E 0:00:00:0961   main.gd:3 @ _ready(): Node not found: "Pivot/Camera" (relative to "/root/Root/Player").
  <C++ Error>    Method/function failed. Returning: nullptr
  <C++ Source>   scene/main/node.cpp:1364 @ get_node()
  <Stack Trace>  main.gd:3 @ _ready()
```

(I got the code from https://kidscancode.org/godot_recipes/3.x/g101/3d/101_3d_07/index.html and edited it to hopefully fix some errors)

What I've tried:

Removing the `@` on `@onready` (I've seen `onready` without the `@` on other forums too):

```
Error at (3, 1): Unexpected "Identifier" in class body.
```

Removing the entire `@onready`:

```
Parser Error: The default value is using "$" which won't return nodes in the scene tree before "_ready()" is called. Use the "@onready" annotation to solve this. (Warning treated as error.)
```

**My second problem (player falls through floor):**

I have a `MeshInstance` (the floor mesh) inside a `CollisionShape3D`, and also the player has two `CollisionShape3D`s, but none of the colliders actually work.

I tried changing the last lines of my code (see first problem) to this:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity.y += gravity * delta
    var desired_velocity = get_input() * max_speed

    velocity.x = desired_velocity.x
    velocity.z = desired_velocity.z
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector3.UP)
```

But then it crashes:

```
Too many arguments for move_and_slide() call. Expected at most 0 but received 2.
```

When I change the `@onready` to `onready`, it works, but I will get an error:

```
Error at (3, 1): Unexpected "Identifier" in class body.
```

My node structure is like this:

```
Root (Node3D)
  Collider (CollisionShape3D)
    Terrain (MeshInstance3D)
  Player (CharacterBody3D)
    Body (CollisionShape3D)
    Feet (CollisionShape3D)
    Pivot (Node3D)
      Camera (Camera3D)
  Light (DirectionalLight3D)
```

(The `Root/Player/Pivot` node is a `Node3D` since I don't know how to create a `Spatial`)

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix these issues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

---

### On picking your tutorials

You seem to have been mixing Godot 3 and Godot 4 tutorials. So be careful which one the tutorial is for. *Chances are that tutorials prior to Godot 4 don't specify.*

*At the time of writing, in the kidscancode.org website you can tell by the 3.x or 4.x banner on the top right. Also, at the time of writing, the Godot 4 tutorials might be missing parts.*

In this case, the following is Godot 3:

- `onready` is a keyword.
- The 3D `Node` class is called `Spatial`.
- The characters in 3D are made with `KinematicBody`.
- `move_and_slide` returns a velocity, and takes a velocity as first parameter among other things. So code looks like this:

  ```
  velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector3.UP)
  ```

And these are Godot 4:

- `@onready` is an annotation.
- The 3D `Node` class is called `Node3D`.
- The characters in 3D are made with `CharacterBody3D`.
- `move_and_slide` takes no parameter, returns if there was a collision (`bool`) and works with the properties of the `CharacterBody3D` (such as `velocity` and `up_direction`). So code looks like this:

  ```
  move_and_slide()
  ```

*Since you are working on Godot 4, the rest of this answer will be only about Godot 4 (although similar concepts apply in Godot 3, the class names are differences).*

---

### On the floor collider

The floor problem is the easier to address, although it begets some explanation.

First of all, `CollisionShape3D` do nothing on their own. They work as children of a `CollisionObject3D`.

So you need a `CollisionObject3D`, of which there are a few: `Area3D`, `CharacterBody3D`, `RigidBody3D`, `StaticBody3D`. IN THIS CASE, you are making a floor, so I would guess you would want an `StaticBody3D`.

*In other context you would need a different kind of `CollisionObject3D` depending on what you are doing. I cover that with a bit more depth [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76784237/402022).*

---

Thus, modify your scene tree from this:

```
Root (Node3D)
  Collider (CollisionShape3D)
    Terrain (MeshInstance3D)
```

To this:

```
Root (Node3D)
  Floor (StaticBody3D)
    Collider (CollisionShape3D)
      Terrain (MeshInstance3D)
```

In fact, I would make the `MeshInstance3D` a sibling:

```
Root (Node3D)
  Floor (StaticBody3D)
    Collider (CollisionShape3D)
    Terrain (MeshInstance3D)
```

*Pick names that make sense to you, of course.*

---

### On the node not found

I don't know what is the issue with the following line:

```
@onready var camera = $Pivot/Camera
```

It looks correct to me, assuming it is in the `CharacterBody3D` in this configuration on the scene tree:

```
  Player (CharacterBody3D)
    Pivot (Node3D)
      Camera (Camera3D)
```

Which seems to be the case given the information in the question.

As for making the line work, the best I can suggest is to double check the names, and that you are not getting other errors on the script.

However, **I do not see where you are using `camera` on your script, so you might be able to just remove the line.**